# Universal link is not working with react native IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to integrate universal linking in my react native project, it works properly in android while in IOS it's not working, but deep linking it working properly.

when I tried to open the https url ex: https:example.com it is opening is safari it's not redirected to the IOS app

```
{
 "applinks": {
 "apps": [],
 "details": [
  {
    "appID": "<Team_ID>.xxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xx.xx",
    "paths": [
      "NOT /_/*",
      "/*"
    ]
  }
 ]
}}
```

I have added the following code to AppDelegate.m

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
     openURL:(NSURL *)url
     options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
  {
     return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url 
   options:options];
   }

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity: 
 (nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
     restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^) 
  (NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
   {
    return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
  }
```

also I have enable Associated Domains in apple developer

[image: my entitlement]

any idea if something is missing?

I'm using react native v0.63.3

Comment: Not sure what your json is but if this is your site-association file the format is incorrect https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/applinks

Comment: @NicolasBraun also this format is not working

Comment: Can you paste link to your hosted association file? Also if you domain includes www. do not forget them in the entitlements

Comment: @NicolasBraun the domain do not include www.
and the new apple-app-site-association is 

{
  "applinks": {
    "details": [
      {
        "appIDs": [
          "teamID.xxx.xxxxxx.xxx.xx.xx"
        ],
        "components": [
          {
            "/": "/application/*",
            "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /application/"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: @NicolasBraun the  aasa-validator https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ is giving green bar for the following result:
- https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/
- Your file is served over HTTPS.
- Your server does not return error status codes greater than 400.
- Your file's 'content-type' header was found :)
- Your JSON is validated.

Comment: were u able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please first of all make sure:

1. your `apple-app-site-association` file is under `<domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` route and is accesible.
2. Then use this format to make the file: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains
3. finally wait 5 minutes after the `apple-app-site-association` has been updated and delete the app from your simulator and install it again, then you can test.